# Navigation bar similar to LinkedIn on Android

Tags: android

So for Android's LinkedIn app, there is a navigation bar and once you click on the LinkedIn logo, a subnav will drop down. If you click the logo again it will go back up.

What is this referred to as for Android? What steps would I need to take to produce a similar effect?

I'm no so much looking for someone to do it for me, rather point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) tutorial on how to create a QuickAction dialog. If you scroll down to the bottom it has more of a "menu" type action dialog.